# Can you use Olympus/OM Systems OI.Share app on a single phone to connect to 2 cameras (not at the same time)

Tags: software, olympus, olympus-omd

I have the `OI.Share` app, which fairly seemlessly connects to my OMD E-10 Mk III over WiFi, when I enable WiFi on the body, and connect to its hotspot. This works fine.

I have an OMD E-1 Mk III on order, which supports both WiFi and BlueTooth image transfer.

Can I use 1 phone with `OI.Share` to connect to both cameras? I don't want to connect to both at the same time, but I'd like to be able to connect to whichever camera I'm using at the time, to the app. Or do I need to "forget" the E-10, each time I want to connect to the E-1, and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can connect both.

1. Turn on the camera's wifi/hotspot mode
2. Connect your phone to the device (E-M10KMIII-xyz or E-M1MKIII-xyz)
3. Open the OI.Share app, and it'll connect to the device you enabled Wifi on